# Appending HTML elements to a paragraph removes their formatting?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append a mix of bolded and non-bolded spans to an HTML paragraph element, but the appended spans don't seem to retain any of the formatting they were assigned.

When I try

```
var text = document.createElement("paragraph")
var boldPiece = document.createElement("span")
boldPiece.style = 'font-weight: bold'
boldPiece.innerHTML = variableText
text.appendChild(boldPiece)
```

the resulting `text` paragraph doesn't display the bold formatting for the appended span, it just has that span's plain text.

```html
const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="module">
    var text = document.createElement("paragraph")
    text.innerText += "not bolded"
    var boldPiece = document.createElement("span")
    boldPiece.style = "font-weight: bold"
    boldPiece.innerText = " bolded "
    text.appendChild(boldPiece)
    text.innerText += "not bolded"
    container.appendChild(text)
  </script>
`
```

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1uhxkLav/. Please show how you're adding `text` to the DOM.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, while adding that I believe I figured it out. I was setting innerText for the non-bolded elements, but if I add them by setting innerHTML instead I believe it works as intended.